# Spring & JSP: Accessing variables members through associations

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, member, data-access

I'm trying to display data in a JSP file and I got a question about how deep I can access my data's members (god this sounds wrong).

So I have an entity called `Assignment` which holds OneToOne relations to other entities such as `Project` and `Role`.

For displaying purpose I created a class named `ResourcePlanningItem` which is supposed to hold data from a `Resource` and its corresponding `Assignments` and other stuff. My question is will I be able to access for example the `name` member of the `Role` entity contained in the `assignment` member contained in my `ResourcePlanningItem`?

Something like `${resourcePlanningItem.assignment.role.name}` ? Or is there a depth limit ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that would be fine if they are public and have appropriate getters, and are obviously serialized correctly.

There is no limit - apart from common sense.